# Обработка нажатия клавиши, если окно не активно

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, клавиатура, python-keyboard

Есть программа на *PyQt5*, стоит стандартный обработчик нажатия клавиш,
но если окно программы не активно, этот обработчик просто не обращает внимание на нажатия клавиш, как это пофиксить?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Ui_Settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, Settings):
        Settings.setObjectName("Settings")
        Settings.resize(300, 300)


class Settings(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Settings):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.nativeVirtualKey() == Qt.Key_F:
            self.test()

    def test(self):
        print("Hello world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Settings()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: написать свою ОС

Comment: @Lofectr, Спасибо, как-нибудь попробую

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]  будем думать.

Comment: @S.Nick, спасибо, внёс правки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt может получить доступ к событиям клавиатуры,
только если любое из его окон верхнего уровня имеет фокус клавиатуры.
Если окно свернуто или другое окно сфокусировано, вы не будете получать события клавиатуры.

Единственное решение - использовать внешнюю библиотеку, но у них есть ограничения.

Модуль        `keyboard` https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard ,  похоже, не поддерживает macOS,
в то время как `pyinput` https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput поддерживает,
но для этой ОС требуется `root`-доступ.

В любом случае вам не следует полагаться на синхронизацию проверенных
в данный момент нажатых клавиш, потому что вы наверняка пропустите некоторые события.
Хотя обычно можно использовать отдельный поток, который реализует прослушиватель событий
(которые обычно блокируют),
к счастью, в обоих случаях существуют неблокирующие системы
для вызова функций обратного вызова
(так что на самом деле вам не нужен отдельный поток).

Ниже приведен пример использования модуля `keyboard`:

1. **тест 1**, Нажмите на кнопку `'start'` и понажимайте по клавишам,
   включая клавиши включенные в логику метода `keyboardEventReceived`.
2. **тест 2**, проверьте сочетание клавиш `'alt+s'`, `'ctrl+s'`, `'shift+s'`.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import keyboard


class KeyGrabber(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('start')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.setGrabbing)

        # тест 2
        keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+s', self.onShow, suppress=False)    # Показать интерфейс
        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+s', self.onHide, suppress=False)   # Скрыть интерфейс
        keyboard.add_hotkey('shift+s', self.onQuit, suppress=False)  # Выйти из программы

    # тест 1
    def keyboardEventReceived(self, event):
        if event.event_type == 'down':
            print(f'event.name -> {event.name}')
            if event.name == 'f3':
                print('F3 pressed')
            elif event.name == 'f4':
                print('F4 pressed')
            elif event.name == 'A':
                print('A pressed')
            elif event.name == 'z':
                print('z pressed')
                
    # тест 1            
    def setGrabbing(self, enable):
        if enable:
            self.button.setText('stop')
            # on_press возвращает hook, который может быть использован для "отключения" 
            # функции обратного вызова позже, если это потребуется
            self.hook = keyboard.on_press(self.keyboardEventReceived)
            self.showMinimized()
        else:
            self.button.setText('start')
            keyboard.unhook(self.hook)
            
### # тест 2
    def onShow(self):                                   # тест 2
        self.show()
        self.showNormal()

    def onHide(self):                                   # тест 2
        self.hide()

    def onQuit(self):                                   # тест 2
        keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys()                   #  Отменить все горячие клавиши
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().quit()
           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = KeyGrabber()                            
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]